# Understanding Rubocop "code unreachable" cop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have the following statement

`if !defined?(proxy) || proxy.blank?`

and what I am trying to achieve is avoiding undefined methods on a nil object. Thus my intention is to

1. Check if the "proxy" object is defined to begin with
2. Check if the "proxy" object is not blank (but otherwise defined)

Rubocop says "Unreachable code detected" but, as I read it, the object "proxy" can be defined but empty which means the second part of the if statement will be evaluated.

How is the code unreachable?

Comment: try using `blank?` method instead of `blank`.

Comment: How is it possible that the variable is not defined?

Comment: No, this is part of a Chef cookbook - I will try and use "blank?" instead.

Comment: "blank?" still gives the same results - any feedback appreciated.

Comment: What error are you trying to circumvent with `!defined?(proxy)`? Just a `NoMethodError: undefined method \`something' for nil:NilClass` or rather a `NameError: undefined local variable or method \`proxy'`?

Comment: @p11y That variable is created (or not) based on a search. That search can return "nil".

Comment: So the variable is _defined_ but it is `nil`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56158/discussion-between-fred-clausen-and-p11y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit* based on our [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56158/discussion-between-fred-clausen-and-p11y):

`defined?` is not the right approach, it will check whether a variable is not defined, not what its value is. It operates on a meta-level, so to speak. Think of the `defined?` keyword as answering the question "Was this thing declared anywhere in the code before?".

Normally, you would check for a `nil` value using the `Object#nil?` method. That is the way to ask the question "Is this variable empty?". Your code probably declares the `proxy` variable in any case, which is the reason why the code inside the if-statement is unreachable: `proxy` will *never* be undefined.

You can thus write

```
if proxy.nil? || proxy.blank?
  # ...
end
```

Comment: By the way: if `blank?` would not be a possible case and you were only checking for `nil?`, you could boil the initialization down to `proxy ||= some_value` which basically means `proxy = some_value if proxy.nil?`. This is a very common and useful pattern.

Comment: If you use `blank?` from active_support, you don't need the `nil?` and it will also check for false, empty string and empty collection. [blank? documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)